# Inclusion and quotient mappings in exact sequences

Tags: linear-algebra, quotient-spaces, exact-sequence

I have problems with understanding the role of inclusion mappings and quotient mappings in an exact sequence:

Let $V$ be a vector space. Let $U\subseteq V$ be a subspace of $V$. Then, $0\rightarrow U\rightarrow V\rightarrow V/U \rightarrow 0$ is an exact sequence.

Why does the inclusion mapping ($U\rightarrow V$) imply an injection between $U$ and $V$? Furthermore, why does $\ker(V\rightarrow V/U)=\text{im}(U\rightarrow V)$? Finally, why does $\ker(V/U \rightarrow 0)=\text{im}(V\rightarrow V/U)$?

Comment: What's the question? The inclusion is injective by definition, and its image is $U$.  The quotient map is surjective (again by definition) and its kernel is $U$.

Comment: @Louis Yeah. Sorry, I just did not think of definitions.